# retrieve data from last year

Tags: date, sqlite

I just started in SQLite and I'm trying to retrieve the number of orders 
made in the previous years, in my table named `Commande`.
The query I tried gives no results but I can't 
figure why:

```
select count(id_com)nOrder, strftime('%Y',date)prevYear  
from Commande  
where strftime('%Y',date) = strftime('%Y',date)-1  
group by strftime('%Y',date);
```

I also tried the following:

```
select count(id_com)nOrder  
from Commande  
where strftime('%Y',date) in (select (strftime('%Y',date)-1) lastYear  
                              from commande)  
group by strftime('%Y',date);
```

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

In your `where` clause you're comparing the **year** from column `date` with **year - 1** from `date` **of the same table row**. For a given date "2016-05-31" this expression resolves to

```
2016 = 2015
```

which can never be true, so your result set is empty.

If all you need is the count of entries for each year, use your first try and remove the `where` clause. If not you'll need to provide additional information and the DB schema.